# Android connects to java server socket, but server socket is not receiving data

Tags: java, android, sockets

The Android app is connecting to a java server socket in my private network. After that, the app writes a string to the PrintWriter, but on the server side nothing is received.

I already tested the code on the same machine and it gets connected (as the app) plus it receives the string which is sent via PrintWriter.

Android app:

```
class SocketConnector extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.116", Constant.HUB_PORT);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("command", "some_command");
            jsonObject.put("value", "some_value");

            out.println(jsonObject.toString());
            Log.v("json", jsonObject.toString());

            Log.v("Echo: ", in.readLine());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NetworkErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Java server:

```
while (true) {

    //Open socket
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constant.SOCKET_PORT);

    //wait for client connection
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    //create input/output streams
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Connected");

    String jsonString;

    while ((jsonString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }


    System.out.println(jsonString);

    //pass command and value to handleCommand method
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject response = handleCommand(jsonObject.getString(Constant.JSON_COMMAND), jsonObject.getString(Constant.JSON_VALUE));

    out.println(response.toString());

    serverSocket.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

}

I expect that the android app sends the data correctly or the java server socket receives the sent data properly.

Comment: Is the socket connecting?

Comment: Yes, it is connecting. The Server socket then waits at in.readLine(). The app afterwards sends the string to the PrintWriter, but either the app won't send it properly or the server socket is not receiving the string properly.

Comment: Not sure why it would work "same machine" but not device-to-server. I would suggest doing a tcpdump on the server.

Comment: I don't understand that either... Did it with wireshark (java server is currently on my windows machine).
The app sends the data to the server, the server sends an ACK back. After a few seconds the connection gets reset by the server.

Comment: Wireshark's even better. Can you post a screenshot? Want to see the bytes in the data packet. The ACK is to be expected.

Comment: Of course. Hope this is the right one: https://imgur.com/a/zjOYc4a

Comment: Yes, that's right. I don't see anything amiss. I'm tempted to say it's a difference in line-ending conventions, but that doesn't seem to be supported by the docs. My only suggestion is to switch to `in.read()` and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately in.read() only results in "-1" output after the connection is reset.
It's strange that the same code from my android app works as a standalone java method from the same computer.

Comment: I think you may have hidden too much of the complexity of your program while asking your question. Your .pcap shows two connections to the server; one sent 75 bytes, and the other sent 1. Where did the other connection come from? And what prompted the FIN? Nothing in your client code above allows the `in.readLine()` call to timeout. What is closing the client socket? I assume the RSTs took place when you force-terminated the server. (That's how I know there were two connections; there's two RSTs on port 2794).

Comment: Also the creation of the server socket should be outside the `while` loop.

Comment: 1. `PrimtWriter` swallows exceptions. Use a `BufferedWriter`. 2. Don't keep opening and closing the `ServerSocket`. Create it ahead of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't stop thinking about this, because it seems so strange. I have an explanation, though, so I will take a stab at the answer:

You have two client connections reaching the server. Connection 1 connects and doesn't send anything (reason unknown). Connection 2 connects and sends the data payload. The server never even attempts to read that payload, however, because it's stuck dutifully waiting for connection 1 to send something (which it never does). The second socket is never even `accept()`-ed.

Naturally, when you examine the server with a debugger, you see it waiting on a `readLine()`. Your mistake was assuming that `readLine()` was associated with connection 2.

This jives with the .pcap, by the way; even if a client connection isn't `accept()`-ed, it still gets an ACK, and it is free to send further data to the server. Such data will also be ACK'd. After all, the server OS is in receipt of the data; your server program simply hasn't asked for it yet.

There are any number of reasons why this might work when you do a localhost test; most likely, it's timing-related.

Comment: Thanks @greeble31!
I checked my code and as you stated in the comments of my question: There's code which is establishing a connection before my actual code which is in the question.
Before I am scanning the /24 network for a open port (trying to connect the socket)
Afterwards the ip, which the socket successfully connects to is used in the code in my question more. 
Therefore it can't connect, because it once accepted a connection.